# How to detect large galaxies using thresholding?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm required to create a map of galaxies based on the following image,

http://www.nasa.gov/images/content/690958main_p1237a1.jpg

Basically I need to smooth the image first using a mean filter then apply thresholding to the image.

However, I'm also asked to detect only large galaxies in the image. So what should I adjust the smoothing mask or thresholding in order to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 0):

Both: by smoothing the picture first, the pixels around smaller galaxies will "blend" with the black space and, thus, shift to a lower intensity value. This lower intensity can then be thresholded, leaving only the white centres of bigger galaxies.